# sidekiq delayed a job in millisecond or other unit of time?

Tags: delayed-job, sidekiq

I find in official doc exemple like: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

```
MyWorker.perform_in(3.hours, 'mike', 1)
MyWorker.perform_at(3.hours.from_now, 'mike', 1)
```

I want to know where and how change the definition of units of time used?

If I want Scheduled a job in millisecond or microsecond, it's possible? how? What is the smallest unit of time can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit is float, so you can say `perform_in(3.5.seconds, ...)`.  That won't do you much good though because Sidekiq's scheduler is not meant to be precise.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs#checking-for-new-jobs

Comment: not meant to be precise because you can't predict the execution time of jobs that can cause delay, but in practice, if we know it's execute very quickly, it should work, right?

Comment: If you want it to execute quickly, you should look for an in-process solution.  Going to Redis introduces unpredictable network delay.